# Can pure CSS change other element on hover if its not child element?

Tags: html, css

Does css include possibility to change other element on `hover`. Because I'm kinda struggling with simple task. For this example, I want `form` to appear when you hover `<a> tag`.

```
<a id="log" href="#">text</a>
      <form id="form" action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="id"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>  
      </form>
```

Should css look something like this:

```
#form{
    opacity:0;
}
#log:hover ~ #form {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

or:

```
#log:hover + #form {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

It really drives me crazy :/ Any suggestions how I could make it work? I don't want to use javaScript if there is other way.

Comment: How about making the form nest in a div and display:block and display:none solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write it as -

```
#form{
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); /*For IE8*/
}

#log:hover ~ #form {
    opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); /*For IE8*/
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NUBkp/2/)

Comment: @Ark: *what* 'ugly' CSS? Which part bothers you?

Comment: @Ark Filter is used to support opacity in IE8.... do you have any alternative for the same?

Comment: who asked for a solution for ie8?

Comment: @Ark the OP has already posted correct answer in his question... IE8 solution is just an assumption considering he must be struggling in IE8

Comment: Thanks @Dipaks. I thought I should use ~ or + and I have no idea how I missed them, because I was looking for this all day. Thanks again ;]

Answer (score 8):

```
#form {
  display: none;
}

#log:hover ~ #form {
  display:block;
}

#form:hover {
  display:block;
}
```

You'll need `#form:hover` so that the form doesn't disappear when you stop hovering the link, but this will not work if you're on a touch device. `#log:active ~ #form` may work on touch, can't confirm right now.

e.g: http://jsbin.com/etuxab/1/edit

Comment: Thanks @mdk for pointing issue about touch devices. I guess I will use alternative css for them. Thanks for help again ;]